# USB host mode on Android receives strange leading data bytes when connected to serial adapter

Tags: android, usb

While my routines sends and receive the data between Android device and PC without any problems I have a strange issue.

All the messages I receive only on the Android side have two leading bytes that do not come from any of my data.

so when I send 01 02 03 as hex from the PC to Android device I receive "B1 60 01 20 03" this happens with all PCs or other devices - so it must be in my read routine somewhere - since other Android Apps that I tried do not receive the "B1 60" leading bytes.

This is how I read from USB:

```
lenOfPartialChunksBuffer = mDeviceConnection.bulkTransfer(
            mFTDIEndpointIN, bufferForPartialChunksOfAnswer, 4096,
            commMsg.timeoutForUSBBulkTransfer);
```

Anybody experienced something similar?

ps - no matter which device I connect to USB serial adapter - I keep getting these 2 extra bytes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a novice android programmer like yourself. What I can tell it might have something to do with your android phone/tablet. I recommend that if you can spare the two bytes in your protocol, just shift over the two bytes. That's what I did and it worked fine.